# How to create a progress dialog inside of AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have a FullRest API which returns a StatusCode, and I succeed, the problem is, the progress dialog cannot be called from AsyncTask, I just want to "show" the user what's happened, `if(statusCode == 201)`.. Successful POST, so far :

PostBaseClass..

```
public class PostBase {

private static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
private String Url="http://192.168.0.101:3000/";

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

 int POST(final PostModel model) throws IOException{
     Gson gson = new Gson();
     String modelJson = gson.toJson(model);

     RequestBody body =  RequestBody.create(JSON,modelJson);
     Request request = new Request.Builder()
             .url(Url + "api/gone/POST")
             .post(body)
             .build();
     Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
     return response.code();
}
```

MainActivity..

```
public void MakePost(final PostModel postModel){
    new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                PostBase postBase = new PostBase();
                statusCode = postBase.POST(postModel);
                if(statusCode == 201){
                  //TODO
                }else {
                  //TODO
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

`onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` run on the ui thread while you cannot update ui from `doInBackground` as it runs on a background thread

So display dialog in `onPreExecute` and dismiss dialog in `onPostExecute`

Return some value in `doInBackground` and do what is necessary in `onPostExecute` based on the value returned.

If you want to show progress of the upload you can do that using  `onProgressUpdate`

```
new AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>(){

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
      super.onPreExecute()
      // runs on the ui thread
      // show dialog
    }  
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            PostBase postBase = new PostBase();
            statusCode = postBase.POST(postModel);
            if(statusCode == 201){
              return "successful";
            }else {
              return "notsuccessful"
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return "something";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
      super.onPostExecute();
      // dismiss dialog
      if(result.equals("successful")
      {
        // do something on successful
        // runs on the ui thread so do update ui
      }
    }   
}.execute();
```

Apart from the asynctask code it looks like you  are using `Retrofit`. You can also make asynchronous calls with the same.

Answer (score 1):

Place your ProgressDialog in onPreExecute, sample code below:

```
private ProgressDialog pd;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){ 
   super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(yourContext);
        pd.setMessage("Loading...");
        pd.show();    
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
   super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd.dismiss();
}
```

Thanks